# SSIS compare 2 results?

Tags: sql, ssis

I am hoping someone can help me. I am building an SSIS package that will have 2 OLE DB Sources that will get data via SQL command.

My question is, how can I compare the two results?

The results should contain the same amount of rows, but how would I get my package to show for example, rows included in Source A but haven't come through in Source B?

Hope that makes sense?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: why don't you join the results with a FULL join?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i got your question correct, but i would maybe use a merge join with full join. Remember to make your source IsSorted set to true.

Do you want something like this?:

[image]